# How do I remove allele annotations from SNP Ids in .bim file?

Tags: snp, plink, linux

Hello every one i need help in editting my .bim file. So my .bim file looked like following. I want to convert the ids with chromosomal position from `chr1_867635_C_T` to `chr1_867635` while others remained as it is. I want to remove all the alleles from my SNP IDs, not just specific ones.

```
1       rs2880024             866893  A       G
1       chr1_867635_C_T       867635  A       G
1       chr1_869303_C_T       869303  A       G
1       chr1_873558_G_T       873558  C       A
1       exm2275405           879439  A       G
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to remove the first occurrence of a `_` followed by a capital letter, another `_` and another capital letter from each line:

```
$ sed 's/_[A-Z]_[A-Z]//' file 
1       rs2880024             866893  A       G
1       chr1_867635       867635  A       G
1       chr1_869303       869303  A       G
1       chr1_873558       873558  C       A
1       exm2275405           879439  A       G
```

Alternatively, find the first occurrence of `chr` followed by numbers, then an underscore and more numbers and remove all non-whitespace characters after the last numbers (note that this assumes GNU `sed`, the default on Linux systems):

```
$ sed -E 's/(\schr[0-9]+_[0-9]+)_\S+/\1/' file 
1       rs2880024             866893  A       G
1       chr1_867635       867635  A       G
1       chr1_869303       869303  A       G
1       chr1_873558       873558  C       A
1       exm2275405           879439  A       G
```

If your file is more varied than you show, you can use this to ensure you only make the change on the 2nd field:

```
$ awk -F'[ ]' '{ sub(/_[A-Z]_[A-Z]/,"",$2)}1' file 
1       rs2880024             866893  A       G
1       chr1_867635_C_T       867635  A       G
1       chr1_869303_C_T       869303  A       G
1       chr1_873558_G_T       873558  C       A
1       exm2275405           879439  A       G
```

Or, the same but only matching A, C, T or G:

```
$ awk -F'[ ]' '{ sub(/_[ACTG]_[ACTG]/,"",$2)}1' file 
1       rs2880024             866893  A       G
1       chr1_867635_C_T       867635  A       G
1       chr1_869303_C_T       869303  A       G
1       chr1_873558_G_T       873558  C       A
1       exm2275405           879439  A       G
```

Comment: The output of these commands should be piped out to another file (e.g. using `>`)

Comment: Yep. Either that, or add an `-i` to the `sed` commands and a `-i inplace` to the `awk` (assuming GNU `awk`) commands to edit the file in place.